# Singular normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$: Where is it regular? (EDIT WITH ATTEMPT)

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\xi = (1,1)^T$ and $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

This clearly defines a singular normal distribution, call it X.

I've read online that this means $X$ is concentrated on a subspace of dimension lower than 2. My first question: **Why does this mean that??**

I now want to find an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $V = v_0 + U$, where $U$ is a linear subspace, such that $P(X \in V) = 1$ and $X - v_0$ is regularly distributed on $U$. **How do I do this??**

MY ATTEMPT AFTER EDIT:

One can show that $X - \xi$ with mean $(0,0)^T$ and variance $\Sigma$ is merely given by $CY$ where $Y = (Y_1, Y_2)^T$ is standard normally distributed and $C$ is $$\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 \\ -\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 \end{pmatrix}$$ The image of $C$ is a subspace of dimension $1$. We let this equal $U$. As $C$ is a surjective map onto $U$, $CY$ is regular on $U$. Also, $X - \xi$ lies with probability $1$ in $U$, so $X$ lies in $U + \xi$ with probability $1$.

My questions: 1) Is this even correct?

2) Why does $X$ not just lie in this space? Why do we have to say that it lies with probability $1$?

3) Is there not an easier way to do it? I had to contruct $C$ by first ortogonally diagonalizing $\Sigma$ and using that to find a $C$ such that $\Sigma = CC^T = C I C^t$, where $I$ is the variance matrix of the standard normal...

Comment: A singular covariance matrix means that variance of some linear combination of components is zero which implies that that linear combination is constant which means that your random variable lives on some subspace of lower dimension.

Comment: A naive way to think about this:  let $X_1 \sim \operatorname{Normal}(1,1)$, and $X_2 = 2-X_1$.  Then $\boldsymbol X = (X_1, X_2)$ has the properties described, since the covariance of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is $-1$.  This indicates that $\boldsymbol X$ is really a univariate random variable in disguise, loosely speaking.

Comment: In full generality, let $\bar X=X-E(X)$, consider $\Sigma=E\left(\bar X\bar X^T\right)$ the covariance matrix of $X$. Since $\Sigma$ is singular, there exists some nonzero vector $v$ such that $\Sigma v=0$. Thus, $E\left((v^T\bar X)^2\right)=E\left(v^T\bar X\bar X^Tv\right)=v^T\Sigma v=0$ hence $v^T\bar X=0$ almost surely, that is, $P(X\in U)=1$ where $U=\left\{x\mid v^Tx=v^TE(X)\right\}$ is an affine hyperplane since $v\ne0$. In your case, $E(X)=(1,1)^T$ and $v=(1,1)^T$ works hence $U=\{(x_1,x_2)\mid x_1+x_2=2\}$.